# What is the difference between jni compile cpp and c?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

test.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

jstring Java_com_test_b_hello_hellostr( JNIEnv* env,jobject thiz )
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
}
```

This compilation is OK. But compile has the error when I change to test.cpp.

libb/jtest.cpp: In function '_jstring* Java_com_test_b_hello_hellostr(JNIEnv*, _jobject*)':
jtest.cpp:108: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type '_JNIEnv'
make[1]: *** [out/.../obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libdrvb_intermediates/jtest.o] Error 1

Why it like this? It has the difference between app and c?

I check the system jni.h file: `alps\dalvik\libnativehelper\include\nativehelper\jni.h`
.

```
.
    void        (*ReleaseStringChars)(JNIEnv*, jstring, const jchar*);
    jstring     (*NewStringUTF)(JNIEnv*, const char*);
    jsize       (*GetStringUTFLength)(JNIEnv*, jstring);
...
    jstring NewStringUTF(const char* bytes)
    { return functions->NewStringUTF(this, bytes); }
.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNI for C++ is slightly different from JNI for plain C.

In plain C it is correct to use: `(*env)->SomeFunction(env, arg, arg, ...)`

Note that you must dereference `env` and that the first argument to the function is always `env`.

In C++, it's different.  You use:  `env->SomeFunction(arg, arg, ...)`

You don't need to dereference `env` and you don't pass `env` as the first argument.

The actual calls into Java will be the same.  Java doesn't care whether you use plain C or C++ to do the JNI stuff.

Here's a quick introduction to using C++ for JNI.

http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/cpp.html